# Play Framework Deletes DB at Test Mode

Tags: unit-testing, junit, playframework

We are using Play! framework in our project and testing our code with unit tests. With the same code all my records in the test database are deleted when I stop the Play server on the console but the dbs  of my workmates are not deleted when they stop Play. How can we resolve this?

PS: I'm using ubuntu 11.04 and tried with play 1.2.1, 1.2.2 and 1.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that you all have the same settings in application.conf. You may have JPA set up to "create-drop" on test, while they have it on "create". This would explain why the database is removed.

Comment: Thx. In my conf jpa set up to "create-drop" :( I fixed this.. :)

Comment: Problem is continues.. But now it deletes on start all db. How can i resolve this? :)

Comment: @Omer the problem is (probably) the same: configuration. Set it to the same config as your workmates, which will probably be "update" (only apply changes to tables at start). If that's not the case, then verify if you have some "OnAplicationStart" job that is cleaning the database. The simplest way will be to compare your code with the code of your workmate that is not having the issue and see what changes :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the same H2 database, you and your colleagues? H2 Mem DB or H2 FS?
If memory, it's normal that the DB is cleaned after tests because the DB in memory is released.

Comment: But do you delete voluntarily the DB or is it something unwanted?

Comment: it was something unwanted :) Problem was from my conf file ;)

Comment: ok I prefer that and the place to look was clearly the conf :)